# Show solution to ODE's fourier series is a series of sines only

Tags: fourier-series, applications

This question was given in an exam in applied mathematics, on the subject of Fourier series:

Observe the following ODE:

$u\left ( x \right) ^{\prime \prime}+Q \left ( x \right) u\left ( x \right) =f\left ( x \right) $

$u\left ( 0 \right)=u\left ( \pi \right)=0$

Where $Q,f$ are continuous functions which are not periodic. We  know that $u \in C^2$ and is not necessarily periodic.

1. Let $\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n \cos{nx}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {b_n \sin{nx}}$ be $u$'s Fourier series. Show that $a_n=0$ for every $n \geq 0$. That is, $u\left ( x \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {b_n \sin{nx}}$.
2. Show that $\left | b_n \right | < \frac{c}{n^2}$

What I tried: not a lot. What we are requested to prove in 1 is equivalent to showing that $u$ is an odd function but I cannot see how to we can obtain that from the ODE. It would seem I am missing the right tools to deal with this section and would appreciate it if you could set me on the right path.

Comment: Hints: 1. Use the boundary conditions. 2. There's a theorem regarding Fourier series saying that if you know $f$ is $p$-times continuously differentiable, then the Fourier series coeffecients of $f$ fall off as $O(n^{-(p+1)})$, so from the differential equation as $u''$ exists...

Comment: @AndrewD There was actually another segment in the question asking us to explain why we cannot apply that theorem to conclude 2 but since I didn't know the theorem or its terms to quote, I didn't bring it in. Could you give a link to the theorem in question? We are also hinted that we should derive 2 by developing the coefficients of the Fourier series.

Comment: @AndrewD I guess this is theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients

I guess we can't use the theorem since $u$ doesn't necessarily has a bounded variation.

Comment: Yeah, it's that one, but I can't really think as to why we can't use that theorem in this context. I don't agree with what you say about $u$ needing to have a bounded variation, as because we know that $u''$ exists, $u$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: As for deriving $2$, off the top of my head I would use the integral expression for $b_n$, then integrate by parts a few times.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ $u$ is not necessary odd, but you can define $2\pi$-periodic odd function $u_1(x)=u(x)$ for $0\leq x \leq \pi$, $u_1=-u(x)$ for $-\pi \leq x \leq 0$. Then you can prove that for $u_1$ you have $a_n=0$, but $u(x)=u_1(x)$ for $0<x<\pi$.

Comment: Then I don't get it: The ODE itself has nothing to do with this result? It all comes strictly from the boundary values?